# Converting string to expression

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to convert a string to an expression?

my string: `var1 == null && var2 != 5`

I want to use this string as a condition of the `if()`, Like `if(var1 == null && var2 != 5)`

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript!

Comment: you need to use eval() functions, but be careful with scopes.

Comment: How to use eval() in this case?

Comment: Where did you get that string from? It's considered a code smell to have executable code in strings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `eval`. This will do

```
if (eval(" var1 == null && var2 != 5"))
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One option is to create and call `new Function`:

```
var strExpr = "var1 == null && var2 != 5";
if (new Function("return " + strExpr)()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This method is safer than eval and much, much faster if you need to call it repeatedly.

Comment: new Function suffers from security and performance issues similar to eval. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 3):

To see how eval works, just write in console:

```
console.log(eval("1==1"));
console.log(eval("1==2"));
```

This will output true and false

Comment: And remember that **eval is evil**

Answer (score 0):

1.) Java and Javascript don't have much in common, but the name and some syntax inherited from C.

2.) Anyhow, you generally should avoid what you are trying to do. In most languages and cases this practice should not be used due to security problems.

Answer (score 0):

The String() function converts the value of an object to a string, you can do eval(String)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var var1 = new String("999 888");
    var var2 = "5";
    var var3;
    var var4 = 8;
    document.write(String(var2)+ "<br>");
    document.write(String(var4)+ "<br>");

    //5
    //8

    if(var3 === undefined && var2 != 6){
            alert('var1='+var1+' var2='+var2);
    }
    var ev=eval(String(var3 === undefined && var2 != 6));
    alert(ev);

    var ev1=eval("var3 === undefined && var2 != 6");
    alert(ev1);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Try it and good luck!